# Installing VTK for Python,debian linux

Tags: python, linux, vtk

I'm trying to install `VTK` module for python, I am however unsuccessful in doing so. I have downloaded two version of `VTK` tar-file and after doing the install process, I received this error in two versions:

```
Errors while running CTest
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 8
```

I hope somebody can help me with this.

Comment: PyVTK 0.5.18 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVTK → PyVTK-0.5.18.tar.gz https://pypi.python.org/packages/6a/dc/d5ffc2cc50bdd7a2e7b435655ee5931d614f7c118624dd20c51440c79337/PyVTK-0.5.18.tar.gz#md5=9775abe951b8219e1ddf98b9b67c5bea .... .... `$ cd PyVTK-0.5.18/ && sudo python setup.py install` : No errors here ! ... What are you doing ? Which command is used ? ... And which OS are you using ? ... All this is supposed to be included in your question : Please edit your question to include information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm installing VTK in debian linux(last version) with the commands in the following website :                                                                              https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306682/how-to-install-vtk-with-python-wrapper-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-rhel/306683                                         But at the end and after   make test   command, it gives me the mentioned error,